# Solving the following maximization problem analytically?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

Is it possible to solve the value of lambda that maximizes the following equation analytically?:

$$ \frac{1-e^{-30 \lambda}}{30 \lambda} - e^{-30 \lambda} $$,

So then the derivative is equal to:

$$ \frac{e^{-30\lambda}}{\lambda} - \frac{30}{900\lambda^2} + \frac{30e^{-30\lambda}}{900 \lambda^2} + 30e^{-30\lambda} = 0$$,

Is it possible to get an analytical solution for lambda or does it need to be solved numerically?

Comment: Clearly your function is maximized at $\lambda = 0$.  Analytic enough for you?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm not so sure about that: [plot1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(1-e%5E(-30+x))%2F(30x)-e%5E(-30x)), [plot2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(1-e%5E(-30+x))%2F(30x)-e%5E(-30x)+from+0+to+1).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $f(0)=0, f(1/30)=1-2e^{-1}>0.$

Comment: Start by setting $30\lambda=x$ to get simpler-looking terms, I would say.

Comment: It might be helpful to observe that
$$ \frac{1-e^{-30\lambda }}{30\lambda} - e^{-30\lambda} = \int_0^1 e^{-30\lambda s} \, \mathrm ds - e^{-30\lambda} = \int_0^1 \left( e^{-30\lambda s}-e^{-30\lambda}\right) \, \mathrm ds.$$

Answer (score 2):

By a simple calculation, a better closed form for the equation is $$e^{-30\lambda}={1\over 900\lambda^2+30\lambda+1}$$defining a new variable $u=30\lambda$ we obtain$$e^{u}={ u^2+u+1}$$ or$$u=\ln u^2+u+1$$ which has a trivial answer $u=0$ and the other roots can only be found numerically. The only non-trivial root is about $1.7933$. The  function $f(u)=u-\ln (u^2+u+1)$ has been plotted below:
[image]

Also the function to be plotted is as following

[image]

As can be seen, the only maximal point is  $u\approx 1.7933$ equivalent to $\lambda\approx 0.0598$

Answer (score 1):

Calling $y = 30\lambda$ we have

$$
f(y) = \frac 1y-\left(\frac 1y + 1\right)e^{-y}
$$

now

$$
f'(y) = \frac{e^{-y} \left(y^2+y-e^y+1\right)}{y^2} = 0
$$

so making approximations

$$
1+y+y^2-e^y\approx \frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3!}-\frac{y^4}{4!}
= 0\to \frac 12 = \frac{y}{6}+\frac{y^2}{24}
$$
and solving we obtain $y = \{-6,2\}$ so with a sufficient approximation the maximum is located at $y = 30\lambda = 2\to \lambda = \frac{1}{15}$

Answer (score 1):

*More than likely too complex but funny (at least to me !)*

Starting from Mostafa Ayaz's answer, we can *approximate* the solution.

Using $x=30 \lambda$, consider
$$f(x)=\frac {1-e^{-x}}x-e^{-x}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{-x} \left(x^2+x+1-e^x\right)}{x^2}$$ making that we look for the zeros of $$g(x)=x^2+x+1-e^x$$ The derivative  $$g'(x)=2x+1-e^x$$ cancels at $x=0$ but also at
$$x_*=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\approx 1.25643$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Now, approximate $g(x)$ by a Taylor expansion around $x=x_*$
$$g(x)=g(x_*)+\frac{1}{2} (x-x_*)^2 g''(x_*)+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ where 
$$g(x_*)=W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right) \left(W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{e}}\right)+2\right)+\frac{3}{4}\approx 0.322188$$
$$g''(x_*)=2 \left(W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right)+1\right)\approx-1.51286$$ All of that gives as an *approximation* of the required root of $g(x)=0$
$$x_0=x_*+ \sqrt{-2\frac{g(x_*)}{g''(x_*)}}\approx 1.90907$$  Using Newton method gives the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.90907 \\
 1 & 1.80890 \\
 2 & 1.79362 \\
 3 & 1.79328 \\
 4 & 1.79328
\end{array}
\right)$$ then $\lambda\approx 0.059776$.

Notice that for $x=1.79328$ the maximum value of $f(x)$ is $\approx 0.298426$ while, for the approximate value $x_0$, it would be $\approx 0.297958$ (not so far !).